# (My)SQL - For showing last Inbox of Messages

Tags: mysql, sql

So hopefully the question is not asked, but I didn't find it.

My example table looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxiFs.jpg

For my SQL I know for example the user ID of 1 and I want to show the Inbox of my Messanger for that I need to know if User ID 1 received a message or was the sender of a message.

For example:

```
sender_id receiver_id
  1         2
  3         1
  1         4
 12         1
```

Should give me four Inbox results for ID 1.

So I currently stuck with

```
SELECT * FROM chats AS tm 
WHERE tm.id IN
(SELECT MAX(id) FROM chats WHERE sender_id = 1 OR receiver_id = 1 GROUP BY receiver_id)
```

This gets me: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rxGy.jpg

You'll see that I don't need ID 2, but I care for ID 3, because it's the latest message of that conversation.

So how can I decide with SQL that I want the latest of sender_id 1 or receiver_id 1?

Thank you!

Comment: No pictures, thanks. For next time, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses a least/greatest trick:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM chats t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        LEAST(sender_id, receiver_id) AS sender_id,
        GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id) AS receiver_id,
        MAX(updated_at) AS max_updated_at
    FROM chats
    GROUP BY
        LEAST(sender_id, receiver_id),
        GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id)
) t2
    ON LEAST(t1.sender_id, t1.receiver_id) = t2.sender_id AND
       GREATEST(t1.sender_id, t1.receiver_id) = t2.receiver_id AND
       t1.updated_at = t2.max_updated_at;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: WOW that is it! Now I have to check what it actually does but it works perfect when I add on the last line:   WHERE t1.sender_id = 1 OR t1.receiver_id = 1

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT * FROM chats AS tm  WHERE tm.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM chats
>   WHERE sender_id = 1 OR receiver_id = 1 GROUP BY receiver_id)

You could try with Top(1) like this

> SELECT id FROM chats
>   WHERE sender_id = 1 OR receiver_id = 1 ORDER BY ID DESC
>   LIMIT 1

This is the last row in chats witch contains a sender or reciver with id 1

Is a first a aproximation (It´s suboptimal)